# nginx send() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) on websocket connections

Tags: nginx, websocket

## env

```
sudo docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a

uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 20:32:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

https-portal
steveltn/https-portal:1

nginx
nginx:1.17.8-alpine

Rails
Rails 5.2.4.1
```

## The Problem

I have setups like this diagram on a cloud server.

[image: setups]

1. https-portal is the main gateway to my web server
2. sends out nextjs (frontend)
3. client sends websocket connection to the rails (backend)
4. client stays connected with the websocket and gets notified

However, on this cloud server, somehow websocket connection gets cut off every about 10 seconds.

To debug, I used `command: ash -c 'nginx-debug -g "daemon off;"'` on the internal nginx, and I noticed `send() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` is happening, but I can't find what is causing this error.

What I don't understand is, if I run the same production-ready images on my local server, websocket works just as expected, and I also don't see `send() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` in local nginx error_log.

The differences between local and cloud I can think of are

1. firewall
2. using https (let's encrypt) / local using self-signed certificate
3. different docker-compose version (local using docker-compose version 1.25.0, build 0a186604, but it's so minor ..)

I am gonna paste one section of the websocket connection failure.

```
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy status 101 "101 Switching Protocols"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy header: "Upgrade: websocket"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy header: "Connection: Upgrade"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy header: "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: PKrqrlhLA2VzzxQ4+c2l2sEdcq8="
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy header: "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: actioncable-v1-json"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http proxy header done
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
nginx_1     | Server: nginx/1.17.8
nginx_1     | Date: Sun, 10 May 2020 13:59:13 GMT
nginx_1     | Connection: upgrade
nginx_1     | Sec-WebSocket-Accept: PKrqrlhLA2VzzxQ4+c2l2sEdcq8=
nginx_1     | Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: actioncable-v1-json
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 write new buf t:1 f:0 00005567D5D3E718, pos 00005567D5D3E718, size: 233 file: 0, size: 0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:233
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 tcp_nodelay
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 tcp_nodelay
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http output filter "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http copy filter: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http postpone filter "/backend/cable?" 00007FFCCD021878
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 write old buf t:1 f:0 00005567D5D3E718, pos 00005567D5D3E718, size: 233 file: 0, size: 0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:233
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http write filter limit 0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 writev: 233 of 233
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http write filter 0000000000000000
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http copy filter: 0 "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 malloc: 00005567D5D3F500:4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048252
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048252
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 20 of 3922
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 20 of 20
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048252
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048252
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http run request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:3 107 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:11 107 of 107
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048404
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http run request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048404
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 111 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 111 of 111
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048408
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:13 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048244, new: 384048408
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 http run request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:3 1137 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:11 1137 of 1137
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer del: 11: 384048244
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer add: 11: 7200000:384048548
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 http run request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:14 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384048548, new: 384048548
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 38 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 38 of 38
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer del: 11: 384048548
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer add: 11: 7200000:384050208
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:15 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384050208, new: 384050208
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:24864
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:24864
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:20768
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:20768
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:16672
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:16672
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:12576
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:12576
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:8480
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:8480
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:4384
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:4384
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:288
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:288
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 288 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 288 of 288
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer del: 11: 384050208
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer add: 11: 7200000:384051948
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051948
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:10384
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:10384
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:6288
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:6288
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:2192
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:2192
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 2192 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 2192 of 2192
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051956
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051956
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 2896 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 2896 of 2896
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 3184 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 3184 of 3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 3184 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 3184 of 3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 3184 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 3184 of 3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:27760
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:23664
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:19568
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:15472
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:11376
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:7280
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 3184 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 3184 of 3184
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 11, old: 384051948, new: 384051960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:59616
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:59616
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:55520
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:55520
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:51424
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:51424
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:47328
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:47328
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:43232
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:43232
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:39136
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: eof:0, avail:39136
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: fd:11 4096 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 recv: avail:35040
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send: fd:3 -1 of 4096
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 send() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer del: 11: 384051948
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer add: 3: 60000:376911960
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream request: "/backend/cable?"
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
nginx_1     | 2020/05/10 13:59:17 [debug] 6#6: *55 event timer: 3, old: 376911960, new: 376911960
```